# Insert Javascript variable value into HTML tag id field

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to organize a bunch of id tags, I would **like** to be able to set up a single JavaScript variable which holds all manner of interesting information. One place I would like to use it, is to set the value of an `id` field in an HTML tag

```
<script>
var messageID = { idText: "message1", other: "qwerty"};
</script>

<div id="message0">Text Zero</div>
<div id="JavaScript.messageID.idText">Text One</div> <!-- abject failure -->
```

So basically I want the `messageID.idText` value to be the `id` value: `id="message1"`. Obviously the example fails in the second div line. Is there a way to do this?

Edit:

Ok, I want to be able to use the value of `messageID.idText` elsewhere in the system, such as

```
var elementTag = document.getElementById(messageID.idText);
```

I use the `id` in many places, and the more there are, the better a chance of mis-typing something. This is not a small project :-)

Comment: Could you try to clarify the question? Do you want to change ```Text One``` to ```"message1"```? Would you like to do this by looping through the ```messageID``` object?

Comment: No, the value of the ```id``` field is used elsewhere for a lookup. Once I find it in the document, then I can reference that object. ```document.getElementById(messageID.idText)```. Since the same value is used in both the ```id``` field and the ```getElementById``` fat finger problems are eliminated

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Do you want to change ```id``` attribute of DOM elements using JavaScript?

Comment: You could start with id="one", then in the window onload event you can use JS to getElementById("one").id = messageID.idText.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I think you would need to implement some sort of server side rendering for this, because you are trying to execute javascript to *generate* the HTML file.

Comment: @AniketGargya Yes you're right. I had not thought of it that way. Guess I'll have to re-organize the code a bit more than I thought and put in server side ```<?= ?>``` sets for both the JavaScript variable and the ```id``` value. Thanks

Comment: @BigGuy If my comment helped, could you upvote it? 

Comment: @AniketGargya Um, I did :-)

Answer (score 0):

So I am going with:

```
<?php
$msgOneId = "message1";
?>
<script>
var messageID = { idText: "<?=$msgOneId?>", other: "qwerty"};
</script>

<div id="message0">Text Zero</div>
<div id="<?=$msgOneId?>">Text One</div>
```

and then

```
var elementTag = document.getElementById(messageID.idText);
```

works